# How to make border for half-circle fade out?

Tags: css

I want to make half border of a circle which fades out at the end, like this:
[image]

I managed to create a border that fades out to the bottom like this:

```css
#cont{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(green, #fff);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#box{
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

However, this circle does not fade out at 50% but on the bottom. Also the border does not become thinner. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it using *positions*. I assume this would give a better understanding on how to make these kind of shapes.

```css
#cont {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(green -50%, #fff);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#box {
  background: #fff;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 0.1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Although you can remove padding and just use same width/heigt, also left:.1% is not needed I think and the box2, right?

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to remove box2. Goodluck.

Comment: I make the width/height bigger to overwhelm the *#cont*.

Comment: As you put the content ininside box, I think it makes more sense to put the padding to #box. But anyways, great solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:after`  as below.

```css
/*#cont{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(green, #fff);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}*/

#box{
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

#box:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  display: block;
    top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```